# How to create the JSON variable's from a form for sending into api?

Tags: javascript, rest, post, get

I am told that a form when submitted takes values in JSON format here named params, and now i have to create variables for different values in that JSON so that i can directly be forwarded to a CRM.
How do i do that, i am blown right now.
There are 3 form fields - name, number and place.

```
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Get request received");

}

function doPost(e) {
var params = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
params = JSON.parse(params);
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("post request received");
}
```

P.S - I am super new to REST and JS

Comment: would you please add the error that you received while parsing the JSON?

Comment: I dont know about error - i just want to know how to create json variable using js so that i can forward it thru and api

Comment: Make sure `e.postData.contents` has data

Comment: Okay, but how do i create json variable into this for name and phone number ?